# Map LDAP specific attribute to Keycloak roles

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I have a LDAP connection set up in my Keycloak. I've managed to import the normal LDAP roles into keycloak with a mapper. In our LDAP we have roles also mapped as user attributes, so like cn, sn, c ... we have **attributeRoles**. Of course these are not really roles from the technical point of view but user attributes(They are used in our application as roles).

What I want to achieve is to map these user attribute roles(attributeRoles) to real roles in keycloak.

Did any of you have this specific problem and managed to solve it somehow?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no way to do this in Keycloak out of the box for the time being, but you can implement this yourself if you want to. Maybe they will have this in a future release. Would be cool.

Comment: I've managed to implement this in Keycloak by myself. If anyone needs some pointers please let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to find the best way to implement exactly this, which options did you choose?

Comment: Hi. I have adjusted the RoleLDAPStorageMapper.java class in the onImportUserFromLDAP function.

Also do not forget to import the roles in the UserAttributeLDAPStorageMapper.java in onImportUserFromLDAP as well. 

It seems that I can't add code here because I do not have enough room for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the onImportUserFromLDAP in the RoleLDAPStorageMapper with the following code:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> attributes = ldapUser.getAttributes();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : attributes.entrySet()){
        if(entry.getKey().equals(<ATTRIBUTE>)){
            // Try to import the attribute to Keycloak roles
            importAttributesFunction(user, realm, entry.getValue());
        }
    }
```

and here you have the importAttributesFunction:

```
public void importAttributesFunction(UserModel user, RealmModel realm, Set<String> sRoles) {
    for(String sRole: sRoles){
        RoleContainerModel roleContainer = getTargetRoleContainer(realm);
        RoleModel role = roleContainer.getRole(sRole);

        if (role == null) {
            role = roleContainer.addRole(sRole);
        }

        if(!user.hasRole(role)) {
            user.grantRole(role);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I wonder if you can help - I'm trying to make a similar change in KC 3.1.0, I've managed to locate the correct class however the .class files themselves appear to be encoded in a format I'm not able to open as readable text, how did you get around this, different IDE?

Comment: Hi Tom.

First of all you need to get the git project running locally on your machine: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak. After that you need to do your changes, build and then build for distribution.Check the "Starting Keycloak" part on github page. 

Hope it helps.